# parse.com returns "unexpected token %" for curl command that contain accented characters

Tags: json, http, curl, parse-platform, utf-8

I am trying to save a object to my parse server through curl commands.

the curl command that i am using is:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXX" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: XXXXX" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 " \
--data-urlencode " {\"name\": \"Víkingur Reykjavík\"} " \
http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/classes/Test
```

But i keep getting this as a response:

```
{"error":"Unexpected token %"}
```

I found this weird because i don't have a "%" in my name's.
So i tried to look it up through a proxy and found that the json text that is send is:

```
%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22V%EDkingur%20Reykjav%EDk%22%7D%20
```

i am using --data-urlencode which decodes it if i don't use it the object is saved but all the characters with accents will be replaced with a "�".

How should i change the curl so that i will be able to save objects with accents correctly?

Answer (score 0):

JSON data payloads can't be URL-encoded since your content type says it's application/json in utf-8 encoding.

The string should look more like this:

```
{"name":"V\u00edkingur Reykjav\u00edk"}
```

Depending on what tools and languages you have available, you can encode data to JSON in various ways.